# Find Color Value Relative to another Color

Tags: css, colors, sass

I use .scss to variablize as much as I possibly can with my CSS. It is trivial to variablize one color, say `$primary-color`. I would like to use shades of that color and I can easily identify the variant color in Photoshop or any color picker. I can also use the `darken($primary-color, 10)` function in .scss to produce a color and then, through trial and error, come close to the variant color.

How to I take `#1D3B6C`and to find precisely where `#DAE5F0` lies relative to it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult problem as described here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference

I recently solved (at least enough for my purposes) this issue in server-side code by approximation. Our colors are in rgb. The formula I used is this. R,g and b are one color and r1,g1,b1 is the other :

```
var diff = Math.sqrt((r-r1)^2 + (g-g1)^2 + (b-b1)^2)
```

If diff is 100 or less (you can play with the breakpoint and see what works for your situation), I determined the colors shouldn't be together and I go for a default.

I don't know sass but maybe this helps somehow? If there's any way to use JavaScript in the browser, in sass (lile i said, dont know sass) or maybe in your build process somewhere, this will work.

Comment: This is the closest I've found. Though it only makes the trial and error game a little easier. 
http://sassme.arc90.com/

Comment: What's the difference between darken() and converting to HSL and reducing luminosity by a constant percentage?